# HTML trying to load interpolation before constructor on typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm build a angular6 project, and having some troubles.

here is the issue: i'm getting an error on HTML Console, after reloading my page I get a well known error message, I kind of know the issue, it's because on the moment my HTML is being loaded/created the variable atual is undefined.

But my question is: why is the html being loaded before the constructor of my component.ts is called?

I can get the data eventually, but can't understand what i'm doing wrong. Do I have to subscribe the event in some place before the constructor?

[image]

I have a home.component.ts

```
atual: Atual;
homeService: HomeService;

constructor(_homeService : HomeService) { 
this.homeService.getAtual().subscribe((res: any) => {
  console.log('Why is it called after html?');
  this.atual = res.data;
});
```

atual.ts

```
export class Atual {

  public temperature: number;
  public wind_direction: string;
  public wind_velocity: number;
  public humidity: number;
  public condition: string;
  public pressure: number;
  public icon: string;
  public sensation: number;
  public date: string;

}
```

my home.service.ts

```
getAtual(): Observable<Atual[]> {
return this.http.get('./assets/atual.json')//, options)
    .map((response: Response) =>{
      return response.json();
    } )
}
```

and my home.component.html

```
<div>
  <mat-card>
    <img mat-card-lg-image src="../../assets/img/1.png">
    <mat-card-title>{{atual.date}}</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

even with the error, the data is displayed after the service subscribes.
I imagine is because it eventually goes in the constructor in my component.ts, but shouldn't it be like this at the start?

[image]

Comment: Use `{{atual?.date}}` instead, it's the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)

Comment: thanks, it helps with the console error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor **is** called immediately, but `getAtual` is asynchronous. This means that the code inside `subscribe` is not called immediately, as your service has to go off and get the data first.

To avoid the error, you can use `{{atual?.date}}` instead, it's the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) so it will only try to display `date` if `atual` is defined

Answer (score 1):

You can give `atual: Atual;` initialize with an instant of Atual class so it not `undefined`

```
 atual: Atual = new Atual();
```